# USB Wifi Issues with Netgear A7000

Tags: netgear

So I've been running 20.04 with an older USB Wifi nic for a while and had no issues. I replaced the nic with a new Netgear A7000.

I dual boot with Windows and it works fine there but not in Ubuntu. I have tried installing rtl8814au and rtl8812au and neither work.

**I have also found that lsusb never responds with any info on the device. It just sits there and never outputs any info**

Another weird side effect since trying to install this is when I try to reboot the machine it just hangs and eventually I have to physically power off.

dkms status lists:

```
nvidia, 440.64, 5.4.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed

nvidia, 440.64, 5.4.0-29-generic, x86_64: installed

openrazer-driver, 2.8.0, 5.4.0-28-generic, x86_64: installed

openrazer-driver, 2.8.0, 5.4.0-29-generic, x86_64: installed

rtl8812au, 5.6.4.2, 5.4.0-29-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` and also: `sudo dkms status`

Comment: added requested info

Comment: The lsusb issue and the reboot issue suggest much bigger issues than wifi. I think I'd try to fix them first. Can you see any clues in: `dmesg | grep -i -e warn -e error` As the output is probably lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/ndw92CWHqq/

Comment: Your paste suggests that the trouble is with 8814au however, your dkms says that rtl8812au is installed. I doubt that your device is driven by both or either driver. It will be difficult to diagnose without knowing the exact details of your device from `lsusb`. I will propose a preliminary step and let's see if the lsusb and reboot issues are resolved. If so, we'll address the wireless further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to diagnose the 'lsusb' and reboot issue, I suggest that we blacklist the wireless drivers to see if the issue is resolved. We will then find, from 'lsusb' the correct driver for your device.

From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist 8812au"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist 8814au"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r 8812au
modprobe -r 8814au
exit
```

Can you now properly reboot?

Please now show us:

```
lsusb
```

I will add to this question after we gather further information.

Comment: Got this:
modprobe: FATAL: Module 8812au not found.
root@chrisubuntu:~# modprobe -r 8814au
modprobe: FATAL: Module 8814au is in use.

attempting reboot now. Will edit.

Comment: First reboot it hung, but when I got back in it saw the A7000 and allowed me to connect to my network. llusb sees the device now as well. 

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0846:9054 NetGear, Inc. A7000

Comment: So I ran a test on speedtest.net and under windows I get about 350-400 mb down. In Ubuntu I'm getting 250ish or so.

Comment: The correct driver for your device is 8814au and *NOT* 8812au. Since you blacklisted both, I wonder how and why a driver loaded allowing you to connect. Please show us: `lsmod | grep 881`

Comment: doesn't return any info.

chris@chrisubuntu:~$ lsmod | grep 881
chris@chrisubuntu:~$

Comment: lshw -C network shows this:  configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl88XXau ip=10.0.0.110 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11AC

Comment: Ah, haaa! Both 8812au  and 8814au are incorrect. rtl88xxau IS correct. Glad it's working.

Comment: Any idea why my speeds are degraded in Ubuntu VS. Windows?

Comment: None. Please start a new question.